# Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException Could not get application info

Tags: java, android

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException
Could not get application info.
kx0.a (kx0.java:11)
org.chromium.content.browser.ChildProcessLauncherHelperImpl.a (ChildProcessLauncherHelperImpl.java:37)
Bc2.run (Bc2.java:5)
android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:873)
android.os.HandlerThread.run (HandlerThread.java:65)
```

For search, I think this relative with https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/content/public/android/java/src/org/chromium/content/browser/ChildProcessLauncherHelperImpl.java, and I use webview in my app.

Is using webview relative with this error?

But, I really don't know what's this error and how to fix this error.

+) This crash caused in Galaxy Wide2, Android 9(Pie)

Comment: Same thing on a moto e6 g(6) surfna with Android 9. No idea about problem or fix.

Comment: Any news about it? Same here. =(